# Numpy: How to get the sums of integer array slices based on indexes from another array in a vectorized manner?

Tags: python, numpy

Given two integer arrays `a` and `b`, where the elements in `b` represent indices of `a`...

```
a = array([10,10,10,8,8,8])

b = array([0,2,3,5])
```

I want to generate a new array whose elements are the sums of the elements in `a` along the index ranges given in `b`, not including the element at the tail of the range... It's hard to put in words, but the expected result given `a` and `b` from above would be:

```
result = array([0, # sum(a[:0])
                20,  # sum(a[0:2])
                10,  # sum(a[2:3])
                16])  # sum(a[3:5])
```

How could I achieve this in a vectorized/"numpythonic" way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking at [`np.ufunc.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
np.add.reduceat(a,b)
```

Out:

```
# gotta handle the case `b[0] == 0` separately
array([20, 10, 16,  8])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10,10,10,8,8,8])
b = np.array([0,2,3,5])

list(map(sum, np.split(a, b)))
```

It gives:

```
[0, 20, 10, 16, 8]
```

The last number is the sum of the slice `a[5:]`.

Comment: This, while being very concise, is not vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([10,10,10,8,8,8])

b = np.array([0,2,3,5])

result = []


for i, v in enumerate(b):
    result.append(sum(a[b[i-1]:v]))

result = np.array(result)
```

The result:

```
[ 0 20 10 16]
```

Comment: Almost, Except I'm wanting to avoid iteration for performance reasons. In practice, my arrays are much larger. Also, the first element of the result array should be zero per the expected result given in the question. Thank you though!